# «Нашедшему просьба считать печать недействительной»

Tags: склонение

«Нашедшему просьба считать печать недействительной». Нашедшего или нашедшему?

Answer (score 1):

**Объявление в СМИ**

Утеряна печать организации с текстом (), в связи с чем  (с указанной даты) печать объявлена недействительной. К нашедшему просьба вернуть  печать.

Информация из Интернета

Необходимо оценить потенциальную угрозу, которая может возникнуть в результате кражи или утери печати. Если существуют хоть какие-то риски, руководителю фирмы или другому ответственному лицу нужно предпринять самые решительные действия.

Нужно обратиться в полицию с заявление по поводу кражи, дать объявления о пропавшей печати в газеты и электронные СМИ. Нужно связаться с банком, в котором у вас открыт расчетный счет, чтобы они были в курсе относительно пропажи печати. Если эта печать используется при работе с контрагентами, предупредите этих людей о возникших проблемах.

В большинстве случаев будет разумно сменить печать.

Answer (score 0):

**Нашедшего просим считать печать недействительной.**

[Ответ справочной службы русского языка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=246452) 
**Правильно: к нашедшему просьба вернуть.**

Почему только нашедшего? Для остальных она остается действительной?
Обычно нашедшего просят вернуть, а "считать недействительным" адресуют всем (такое объявление о недействительности имеет юридическое значение)

Comment: ну вдруг он захочет пропечатать что-либо..?а тут его предупредили...

Comment: к «нашедшему» только просьба, а «нашедшего» только просят....

Comment: Остальных предупреждать/просить не надо? Если им попадется документ с такой печатью?

Comment: тогда пишут просто про недействительность печати, без «нашедшего» или «нашедшему»...